# How to make gnuplot to NOT plot multiple lines?

Tags: plot, scripting, gnuplot

I am plotting some data and I am getting multiple lines streaking across the plot. There should be one line, so I imagine that gnuplot is trying to fit the data and is joining points or something in a strange way. How can I get gnuplot to plot one like instead of multiple lines? Here is my script:

```
set term png font 'Liberation Sans,10' size 800,200
set output "data/values.png"
set style line 1 lt 1 lw 1 lc rgb "purple" pt -1
set xlabel "Time" font 'Liberation Sans,10'
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
set xtics font 'Liberation Sans,10'
set ytics font 'Liberation Sans,10'
set autoscale y
plot "data.txt" using 1:5 ls 1 smooth bezier with lines
```

[image: Output of the gnuplot script]

Comment: since the line is connected, i'd guess your data isn't sorted by x axis value, so it's going back and forth. if there were disconnects, i'd expect blank lines in the data file.

Comment: I thought of this, the data is sorted by time ... but I will look at it again, I am pulling it from a database, and it has never been out of order.

Comment: if you're using a sql server, then unless you specifically tell it you want the data sorted, it can do whatever it wants. and probably will.

Comment: I am using MySQL ... I am still investigating

Comment: Plot time against line number to check if your data is continous with "plot datafile using 0:1". If this goes up and down you know where you are with your data.

Comment: Btw., it is usually a good idea to reduce your problem to a minimal example before asking for help. This helps yourself understanding the problem, often solving it, and otherwise saves the people you ask a lot of time, not having to dig through irrelevant stuff like e.g. the bezier smoothing in you script.

Comment: Jay Kominek - I got too comfortable with the data always being in order and ran into a case where it was not. Thanks for your earlier comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sort` to sort your data. Consider the following data file which I have generated consistent with your time format:

```
2000-12-21 12:32:05 1
2001-11-21 12:32:05 2
2000-12-20 12:32:05 3
2000-12-20 12:32:04 4
```

Typing `sort data.txt` will yield the correct ordering:

```
2000-12-20 12:32:04 4
2000-12-20 12:32:05 3
2000-12-21 12:32:05 1
2001-11-21 12:32:05 2
```

You can invoke this within gnuplot by using a special input name `plot "< sort data.txt" ...`:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
plot "data.txt" using 1:3 w l
```

[image]

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
plot "< sort data.txt" using 1:3 w l
```

[image]

You can consult the `sort` documentation if you need more powerful sorting with respect to your data format.

Comment: This is a very good response ... I am still probing this issue, and I very much appreciate the response.

Comment: The answer is that the data was not sorted. I had a data file with over 20,000 rows. Usually the data is inserted in order, however in this case it was not. What I did was SORT the data when I extracted it  using "ORDER BY" ... I did take Karl Ratzsch and fiddle around with the data and found some of the places where the data was out of order.